# How would I correctly set a function to be used in a GET request to get persisted auth data?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I want to be able to do a successful Axios `GET` request on the frontend of my website in terms of user `access_token` persisting data from Login component to Dashboard Component (I'm using React.js) on the front.  I've made an attempt in AuthController.php file via `getToken()` function but it still isn't working.  I'm also not sure if I'm calling this correctly inside `api.php` file.  Am I on the right track?

I want it in a way where all I'd need to do in the frontend is:

```
const headers = {
        'Authorization': `${Cookies.get("access_token")}`
    }

    JSON.stringify(headers)

    console.log("inside componentDidMount()");
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login', {headers})
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
 });
```

Here's `AuthController.php`:

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'password' => 'required|string',
        'remember_me' => 'boolean'
    ]);
    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
    if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Unauthorized'
        ], 401);
    $user = $request->user();
    $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
    $token = $tokenResult->token;
    if ($request->remember_me)
        $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
    $token->save();
    return response()->json([
        'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
        'token_type' => 'Bearer',
        'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
            $tokenResult->token->expires_at
        )->toDateTimeString(),
        $user
    ]);
}

public function getToken(Request $request) {
    $user = $request->user();
    $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
    $token = $tokenResult->token;

    if(!Auth::attempt($token))
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Unauthorized!!!'
        ], 401);

    return $token;
}
```

Here's `api.php`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'auth'
], function () {
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('signup', 'AuthController@signup');

    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'auth:api'
    ], function() {
        Route::get('login', 'AuthController@getToken');
        Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
        Route::get('user', 'AuthController@user');
    });
});
```

Comment: You can store the token on your `localStorage` once you get it. And then you can play with it.

Comment: @AkhtarMunir yeah which's what I'm doing above (Cookies instead of localstorage) but it  won't be accepted as Auth.  I keep getting 401 error because auth would only work with email and password but auth_token.

Comment: Do you receive token ?

Comment: @AkhtarMunir yeah I do, it prints successfully

Comment: Well I pass it in this way headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.usertoken}` } you know underline code is enclosed with `  `

Comment: @AkhtarMunir yeah I understand that part, but my php code won't allow that to suffice as viable auth for get request.  I need to configure it that way but unsure how.

Comment: Have you used `JWT`  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213881/discussion-between-cloudyday-and-akhtar-munir).

Comment: Use laravel `Sanctum` or `JWT` for SPA.